# iptables: --protocol tcp with --match tcp, clarification?

Tags: linux, iptables

I see a lot of posts everywhere filtering `iptables` like:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport xxxxx -j ACCEPT
```

which should be equivalent to my line:

```
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --match tcp --destination-port xxxxx --jump ACCEPT
```

---

My question to this line is the meaning of the **--match tcp** as we *should* already know the protocol *is TCP*, or does that trigger anything further? I just don't understand its meaning in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in the explanations below module means *userland iptables command* module, not kernel module (of course there's a relation, but it's not needed for the explanation).

[`iptables`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables.8) deals with IPv4. Every [IPv4 packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure) has a [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers) field. `--protocol tcp` uses a built-in *iptables* code to compare it against the given value. The base *iptables* command itself doesn't know much above the base IPv4 layer. If nothing else requires it, like checking a specific TCP port, *iptables* doesn't go further. Eg:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

will not load the module *tcp*. And there won't be any `-m tcp` seen later.

The base *iptables* command doesn't know about a port. When an unknown option is specified after a protocol is tested, as a courtesy, *iptables* automatically loads the module having the name of the protocol, that's the role of the `-m` option. So under the hood, `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5555` finding no `--dport` option, automatically inserts a `-m tcp` before. Now the `--dport` option is checked again against the *tcp* module, and this module knows about a `--dport` option and handles it. That's why when you do:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5555
```

and dumps back the rules with `iptables-save` you will see in the result this instead:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5555
```

Usually people don't type `-m tcp` but copy any results from a rule dump because it's easier and it means the command won't have a syntax error.

If you want to be convinced of this, here's what happens in those *strace* examples when you give or not give a `--dport` option after having specified the `-p icmp` option for the ICMP protocol (which doesn't have the concept of a port):

```
# strace iptables -A INPUT -p icmp 2>&1 |egrep 'icmp|write'
execve("/usr/sbin/iptables", ["iptables", "-A", "INPUT", "-p", "icmp"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
```

and

```
# strace iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --dport 5555 2>&1 |egrep 'icmp|write'
execve("/usr/sbin/iptables", ["iptables", "-A", "INPUT", "-p", "icmp", "--dport", "5555"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xtables/libipt_icmp.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14464, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xtables/libipt_icmp.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_MATCH, "icmp\0\177\0\0\207\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0!\0\0\0\0\0", [30]) = 0
write(2, "iptables v1.8.3 (legacy): ", 26iptables v1.8.3 (legacy): ) = 26
write(2, "unknown option \"--dport\"", 24unknown option "--dport") = 24
write(2, "\n", 1
write(2, "Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables -"..., 61Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

The presence of an option not known to iptables triggered the loading of the module *icmp* (file `libipt_icmp.so`) because the protocol *icmp* was specified. This module couldn't handle the option `--dport` either and thus *iptables* failed on this command.